# Filter duplicate names in angular

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript

I'm getting this response

```
[
    {
        "Id": 51,
        "RandomId": "4545443434-aa",
        "Name": "James Smith",
    },
    {
        "Id": 21,
        "RandomId": "4545456666-aa",
        "Name": "James Smith",
    },
    {
        "Id": 31,
        "RandomId": "4543443434-aa",
        "Name": "Robert",
    },
    {
        "Id": 41,
        "RandomId": "2535443434-aa",
        "Name": "Lawrence",
    },
    {
        "Id": 71,
        "RandomId": "4534443434-aa",
        "Name": "Mathew",
    },
    {
         "Id": 21,
        "RandomId": "4543453434-aa",
        "Name": "Robert,Lawrence,Mathew",
    },
    {
        "Id": 78,
        "RandomId": "4545343434-aa",
        "Name": "Robert,Lawrence,Mathew",
    },
    {
        "Id": 34,
        "RandomId": "1545443434-aa",
        "Name": "Mathew",
    },
    {
        "Id": 12,
        "RandomId": "4545443437-aa",
        "Name": "Lawrence",
    },
    {
        "Id": 11,
        "RandomId": "4535443434-aa",
        "Name": "Robert",
    }
]
```

I want to filter this response so that there are no repeated names, eg. It should pick first `James Smith` and don't include other with the same name, Same with `Robert,Lawrence,Mathew` it should include first record and other records with the same name should not be included.

Comment: See: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2218999/how-to-remove-all-duplicates-from-an-array-of-objects

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [`Array.reduce()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/Reduce) to only include unique names from your dataset.

For each iteration we add a value to a map object using the `Name` as the key.

Once we've created this map object we use [`Object.values()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/Values) to return an array.

```js
const data = [ { "Id": 51, "RandomId": "4545443434-aa", "Name": "James Smith", }, { "Id": 21, "RandomId": "4545456666-aa", "Name": "James Smith", }, { "Id": 31, "RandomId": "4543443434-aa", "Name": "Robert", }, { "Id": 41, "RandomId": "2535443434-aa", "Name": "Lawrence", }, { "Id": 71, "RandomId": "4534443434-aa", "Name": "Mathew", }, { "Id": 21, "RandomId": "4543453434-aa", "Name": "Robert,Lawrence,Mathew", }, { "Id": 78, "RandomId": "4545343434-aa", "Name": "Robert,Lawrence,Mathew", }, { "Id": 34, "RandomId": "1545443434-aa", "Name": "Mathew", }, { "Id": 12, "RandomId": "4545443437-aa", "Name": "Lawrence", }, { "Id": 11, "RandomId": "4535443434-aa", "Name": "Robert", } ] 
 
const result = Object.values(data.reduce((acc, { Id, RandomId, Name }) => { 
    acc[Name] = acc[Name] || { Id, RandomId, Name };
    return acc;
}, {}));

console.log('Result:', result)
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; }
```

You could also use a [`Map`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Map) to do the same thing:

```js
const data = [ { "Id": 51, "RandomId": "4545443434-aa", "Name": "James Smith", }, { "Id": 21, "RandomId": "4545456666-aa", "Name": "James Smith", }, { "Id": 31, "RandomId": "4543443434-aa", "Name": "Robert", }, { "Id": 41, "RandomId": "2535443434-aa", "Name": "Lawrence", }, { "Id": 71, "RandomId": "4534443434-aa", "Name": "Mathew", }, { "Id": 21, "RandomId": "4543453434-aa", "Name": "Robert,Lawrence,Mathew", }, { "Id": 78, "RandomId": "4545343434-aa", "Name": "Robert,Lawrence,Mathew", }, { "Id": 34, "RandomId": "1545443434-aa", "Name": "Mathew", }, { "Id": 12, "RandomId": "4545443437-aa", "Name": "Lawrence", }, { "Id": 11, "RandomId": "4535443434-aa", "Name": "Robert", } ] 
 
const result = [...data.reduce((map, { Id, RandomId, Name }) => {
    return map.has(Name) ? map: map.set(Name, { Id, RandomId, Name });
}, new Map()).values()];

console.log('Result:', result)
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; }
```

Answer (score 2):

You can filter the existing array like this:

```
result = (result || []).filter((value, index, self) =>
    index === self.findIndex(item => item.Name === value.Name)
);
```

Comment: Thanks will it throw error if result is blank  or null?

Comment: I edited my answer with a solution for that. Now it gives an empty array if result is blank or null.

Answer (score 1):

If you want a **slim** solution, use lodash's [uniqBy](https://lodash.com/docs/4.17.15#uniqBy) method.

```
uniqBy(myArray, 'Name`);
// or
uniqBy(myArray, element => element.Name);
```

Exmaple:

```
import { uniqBy } from 'lodash';

const myArray = [
  {
      "Id": 51,
      "RandomId": "4545443434-aa",
      "Name": "James Smith",
  },
  {
      "Id": 21,
      "RandomId": "4545456666-aa",
      "Name": "James Smith",
  },
  {
      "Id": 31,
      "RandomId": "4543443434-aa",
      "Name": "Robert",
  },
  {
      "Id": 41,
      "RandomId": "2535443434-aa",
      "Name": "Lawrence",
  },
  {
      "Id": 71,
      "RandomId": "4534443434-aa",
      "Name": "Mathew",
  },
  {
       "Id": 21,
      "RandomId": "4543453434-aa",
      "Name": "Robert,Lawrence,Mathew",
  },
  {
      "Id": 78,
      "RandomId": "4545343434-aa",
      "Name": "Robert,Lawrence,Mathew",
  },
  {
      "Id": 34,
      "RandomId": "1545443434-aa",
      "Name": "Mathew",
  },
  {
      "Id": 12,
      "RandomId": "4545443437-aa",
      "Name": "Lawrence",
  },
  {
      "Id": 11,
      "RandomId": "4535443434-aa",
      "Name": "Robert",
  }
];

console.log('before', myArray);
console.log('after', uniqBy(myArray, 'Name'));
```

Stackblitz: https://stackblitz.com/edit/typescript-cpdqfk?file=index.ts